# Why XDocument Elements is always null

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have the following code

```
const string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                            <Revisions>
                                <Revision Key=""MIDTERM"">5850</Revision>
                                <Revision Key=""LONGTERM"">5850</Revision>
                            </Revisions>";
        var key = "MIDTERM";
        var _RevisionsXml = XDocument.Parse(xml, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
        var revisionNode = _RevisionsXml
                                .Root
                                .Elements("Revision")
                                .FirstOrDefault(elem => elem.Attribute("Key").ToString() == key);
```

The revisionNode is always null, not sure what is that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `.Value` instead of `.ToString()` when comparing your key.

Invoking `ToString()` on the attribute will return `Key="MIDTERM"`, which is mostly used for debugging purpose.

Be sure that your XML is well formed or you could face a `NullReferenceException` when calling `.Value` if there is no attribute named `Key`.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure it out later about simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the *value* of the Key attribute:

```
var revisionNode = _RevisionsXml
                        .Root
                        .Elements("Revision")
                        .FirstOrDefault(elem => (string)elem.Attribute("Key") == key);
```